# external raid 1 system basic questions

Tags: external-hard-drive, raid

For my [cubox-i](http://www.cubox-i.com) I would like to have external RAID 1 system in order to have a reliable storage.

1. Do RAID external systems work out-of-the-box or are any additional drivers required? Is there something I should be careful about?
2. Are all hard-drives RAID capable?

Comment: To the close voters: This is not a broad question, as described by the answer. Remember, Superuser is here to help those doing research as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Depending on how you access it, but generally only the host system needs the drivers. When accessing a NAS over the network, or using a USB enclosure with a RAID controller onboard, you won't need to hunt the drivers down yourself. It will present itself to the OS as one hard drive volume already.
2. Yes, all hard drives are RAID capable. This does not mean you can use ANY drive and have great results.

   I will use Western Digital for my following explanations... They use Red, Green, Black, Blue and RE4 drives.

   - The **Greens** are the cheapest, and are power saving. They do not spin too fast, they're quiet, and ideal for archiving data you don't need fast access to.
   - The **Blues** are the middle-of-the-road drives, ideal for inexpensive computers that don't want a Green to boot up their system.
   - The **Blacks** are the speed demons for the home user. They constantly spin at 7,200RPM, and have a larger cache onboard for bursts of reads or writes to go quicker.

   The above drives are not really built for RAID. Yes, they can be used in a RAID system, but they can wait anywhere from 30 seconds to 2 minutes before telling the OS there's an error, which will freeze up the systems wanting access to them. The reason? Because they want to be *sure* that the data is inaccessible, so it keeps trying and trying on the same spot.

   - The **Reds** are built for being on all the time, but also having power saving features of the Green drives. They will alert the OS within 2 seconds (like the RE4s) if there are issues reading the data, so you can replace the disk quickly, and not freeze your system constantly.
   - The **RE4s** are the *RAID Edition* drives, built for the enterprise. They spin fast (like the Blacks), and have the logic onboard to tell the OS when there is a problem, much quicker.

Comment: What's worse than the system pausing to wait for the drive to read a bad block, most RAID controllers (both hardware and software) will kick an entire drive out of the array if it takes "too long" to return from a read request. How long "too long" is varies, but consumer drives timeouts are often far too long for reliable RAID operation in case of read problems, even when redundancy exists. In the case of RAID 0 (striping without parity or redundancy) this can easily kill your whole array if a single sector is bad on a single drive.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Exactly! Especially if you have dedicated RAID hardware, and a non-RAID edition hard drive.